# What is a recipe for a long-lasting, fast draining container soil mix with good aeration?

Tags: soil, containers, potting-soil

I'm interested in making my own container soil for some potted citrus and figs as well as something that'll work for other house plants.  I've heard of [Al's Gritty Mix](http://forums2.gardenweb.com/forums/load/contain/msg0114393114038.html).  Does anyone have a mix that's worked well for them over a several year period?

Comment: http://gardening.about.com/od/seedsavin1/a/Potting_Mix_2.htm

Comment: These seem decent but will they be long-lasting?

Comment: I use a mixture sold at a gardening shop, I think they are okay.

Comment: I made $2 breathable pots out of chicken wire and burlap.  Supposedly good for aeration.  Make a cylinder of the chicken cage wire, weave together with galv. steel wire.  Make 4 cuts at equal distances on one end.  Fold like a you would a cardboard box without tape.  Line the interior with burlap or cheap fabric and pin it using the galv. wire.  Sewing the bottom box-fold is optional since the weight of the soil will hold it, but if you need to move the pot...

Comment: So have you tried anything, and are you able to tell us what worked best  for your case?

Answer (score 7):

Below is a good general purpose container soil mix formula I've heard mentioned on a few different gardening podcasts that I listen to:

- ⅓ sharp sand
- ⅓ screened high quality top soil/loam
- ⅓ high quality compost

Comment: I can never agree sand...there are industrial sea sand and river sand. If mistaken, the cons will be serious. And people just can't distingush them by looking. I will suggest perlite and vermiculite.

Comment: Stupid question: Which is the good one? I'm pondering making my own soil and I have the pacific at my doorstep. Is rinsed sea sand good or bad? And why would it be bad? Isn't it just for aeration and silicon?

Comment: Look closely at the sand grains. they should have sharp edges, like salt crystals. If edges are rounded, like the grains have been through a rock tumbler, it's the wrong stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Al's Gritty mix is:

## For most kind of woody plants

> The basic mix is **1:1:1, pine bark fines:Turface:crushed granite**. It's perfect to grow  that go 2-3 years between repots.

## It's a little different for houseplants

> (note that the 3 parts of all the primary ingredients still works out to a 1:1:1 ratio).
>
> - 3 parts pine or fir bark fines
> - 3 parts Turface MVP (or equal)
> - 3 parts crushed granite (turkey or chicken grit - not crushed shellfish)
> - 1 part vermiculite
> - 1 part coarse silica sand
> - 1 tbsp gypsum/gallon of soil (1/2 cup per cu ft) -- if you use gypsum instead of lime, add 1/8 tsp Epsom salts/gallon of water each time you fertilize

## Some tips:

> - If you want to increase water retention, use 4 parts Turface and 2 parts granite, To reduce water retention, use 4 parts granite & 2 parts Turface. If you vary the recipe to suit yourself, try to keep the organic component at 1/3 or less. No peat/coir is necessary or even desirable in this mix.
> - Though there are a few exceptions, most plants will perform extremely well if you use a 3:1:2 ratio fertilizer (24-8-16, 12-4-8, 9-3-6, are all examples).
> - Fertilizing frequently at lower doses works better.