# Do I have to line the bottom of my vegetable garden with a wire mesh

Tags: vegetables

I'm going to build the a box for my vegetable garden that has a 10" riser with a 6" bevel frame. The idea is this will stop mice from climbing up over the side.

I was at the store pricing out wire mesh to line the bottom to prevent the mice from digging up under it, but the mesh was very expensive.

Do you think a mesh is required? or is there another way to prevent mice from digging under the box?

[image]

Comment: I don't think your frame is going to stop mice climbing over the side; they're unbelievably agile. Are you getting a lot of mouse damage to your veg? I haven't heard of mice causing a lot of garden damage, nor have I heard of them digging. (Not that this isn't possible.) Or do you maybe have voles?

Comment: The mice destroy everything except peppers. Tomatoes planted in containers were safe, so I thought a bevel top on the garden might help, but I wouldn't be surprised if they can still get over the edge.

Comment: mice can get through a hole smaller than a quarter so mesh is not going to stop them. Are you absolutely sure it's mice doing the damage?  I don't live too far from you and seeds and nuts seem to be the food of choice for them

Comment: We do have rabbits in the area, but I've been able to close of the backyard from them. Mouse traps and poison have produced a lot of dead mice, and they eat out the insides of tomatoes just before they are ready to pick. Yea, I'm sure it's mice.

Comment: sounds like you need to get a bunch of cats

Comment: I have a cat. He just sits on the grass watching the mice and does nothing. Lazy fat cat.

Comment: If you want to stop them from digging, you could get a metal landscaping border and bury it around the edge. But I'm not sure if the frame will stop them from climbing.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to your questions? "Do I have to line the bottom of my vegetable garden with a wire mesh", looking for the same answer

Comment: I did, but I'd have to draw a diagram to explain it. I'll post one later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this post](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3344/has-anybody-had-any-success-using-5-gallon-buckets-as-planters) about using five gallon buckets as planters is a relevant solution. It has these advantages:

- cheaper and faster than building the box you have shown
- the smooth sides of the buckets will hinder mice climbing up.  A little silicone lubricant will make the sides extra slippery.
- works for tomatoes, green peppers and many herbs
- you can always increase your protection by using the kiddie pool suggested by LogicalLunatic in the post as a moat