# My avocado trees are having a really hard time

Tags: avocado

I am growing 3 avocado trees. They are about 2 years old and they were doing really well, they have spent winters indoors and summer out side. They are currently inside and I will be moving them outside soon.

I have noticed the youngest leaves are drying or dying out. They aren't going brown. I am not sure what the problem is.

Please can some one give me a little advice on this problem?!

Comment: Pictures would help. What climate/area are you in?

Comment: This may also be useful: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-to-prevent-avocado-from-drying-out-indoors?rq=1

Comment: I'm putting this on hold for now as it appears to be a duplicate of another question. If that's wrong, please add some information to explain the differences between that question and yours, as well as the photographs and details about your climate that were previously asked for. Thanks.